# Events in week view in react-big-calendar are not shown with ellipsis

Tags: css, reactjs, react-big-calendar

I have opened a GitHub issue for this problem on the repository here
https://github.com/jquense/react-big-calendar/issues/2139.

Basically, the events names in week view are not truncated and they appear in a weird way as shown in the below screenshots.

Note that the event starting with Play is not truncated and a part of it appears in next line.

[image]

After applying the ellipsis style to the second last event at the bottom. Now the events appears okay.

[image]

I have figured that the `.rbc-ellipsis` class is not applied to the events in week view but not sure how to fix it in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I am not absolutely positive, but I believe the thinking (of the original development team) was that `events` displayed in the `TimeGrid` views could be a variety of sizes, depending on the time span of the event, and that if you needed something specialized you could always supply a custom `Event` component for a particular `View`. I use one (custom) that does have ellipsis, when needed, and also expands the event on mouseover, and back on mouseout, plus a whole different layout according to the `data`.

Comment: I understand. It is just that the same logic would apply to events in month and day view where the ellipsis is applied by default. So, I feel that not having the ellipsis just in the week view is an oversight and by default should be present.

Comment: I also tried adding the styles to the `eventPropGetter` but those styles are applied to higher `div` and are not inherited by the div that shows the event text.